# How can I use the same class in app and Bundle?

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I'm passing an object from my app to my bundle. The problem is that Swift thinks that they're a different type. So when I do a check it will fail, saying that `MyApp.Restaurant` is not the same as `MyBundle.Restaurant`.

```
func exportRestaurant(_ restaurant: Restaurant) {
    if let restaurant: Restaurant = restaurant as? Restaurant {
        // This will never be executed.
    }
    let restaurant: Restaurant = restaurant as! Restaurant
    // This will crash the app. Could not cast value of type 'MyApp.Restaurant' (0x100ba6460) to 'MyAppSupportingBundle.Restaurant' (0x104eaaec0).
}
```

So, I can not cast it to the type. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: I'm curious why this got a downvote.

Comment: @onnoweb Same here.

Comment: are you redefining a `Restaurant` in your app? if yes, they are definitely not the same.
If not, ,more details are needed, e.g. how you import `Restaurant` into this class you provided above, etc

Comment: @KirilS. I just added to both targets as "Target Membership".

Comment: you shouldn't add Restaurant as part of your project (not directly, not via target membership). Use the one that is provided by framework via `import MyAppSupportingBundle.Restaurant`